# Rutas de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rutas, cms

De antemano gracias, Estoy trabajando en un CMS y quiero separar las rutas del backend y las rutas del front pero tengo conflictos.

El backend por el momento esta en **/admin** y lo que le siga, por ejemplo **/admin/users/etc...**

El problema viene del lado del front cuando quiero por ejemplo poner:
**/paginax** o
**/paginax/paginax2**

Porque ya no puedo entrar al admin cuando declaro las rutas del front:

```
Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
   Route::get('/{slug}/{slug2?}/{slug3?}', 'PageController@routing');
```

Y estas son mis rutas del admin:

```
Route::namespace('Backend')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {

   Route::get('/', 'Sites\SitesController@index')->name('admin.index');
```

Teniendo mis rutas de estama manera, cuando trato de entrar a **/admin** caigo a la ruta `Route::get('/{slug}/{slug2?}/{slug3?}', 'PageController@routing');`

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Tu controlador no tiene validaciones que este provocando eso?

Comment: No tiene, de hecho solo estoy haciendo un return 'routing' en el controlador de PageController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba esto posiblemente si funcione:

```
Route::get('{slug1?}/{slug2?}/{slug3?}/{slug4?}', 'Frontend\PageController@index')->where(['slug1' =>'^(?!.?admin).*'
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias Fernando eso lo soluciono!

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución Fernando, si explicas que realiza este código sería de mucha ayuda a la comunidad, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

¿Lo has intenado de este modo?

```
Route::namespace('Frontend')
        ->group(function () {
            Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
            Route::get('/{slug}/{slug2?}/{slug3?}', 'PageController@routing');
       });

Route::namespace('Backend')
        ->prefix('admin')
        ->group(function () {
            Route::resource('/', 'SitesController@index');
       });
```

[Rutas avanzadas](https://ajgallego.gitbooks.io/laravel-5/content/capitulo_2_rutas_avanzadas.html)

Comment: No puedo agregar el prefijo Frontend porque todas las rutas que le mostraria al usuario quedarian con ese prefijo, necesito que quede limpio por ejemplo:

/
/about
/gallery

Comment: Acabo de actualizar.